# Ajax only displaying first product price rest of the grid is not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, product

i am working on a single page website, where there is grid of products,
visters will simple add that product and press check out to order products,

right there i am facing issue, the products are of dryfruits, which contain 0.5,1 and 2Kg with different rates, by using ajax i am trying to display rate of product based on quantity selected on the spot,but what actually actually happens is that only i am able to get value of first product rest are not displayed on click

here is the code

php and mysql code

```
  <div class="row">
                <div class="container">
                <?php
                    $get_products = "select * from products";

                    $run_products = mysqli_query($connection,$get_products);

                    while ($rows  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_products))
                    {

                        $product_id = $rows['product_id'];
                        $product_name = $rows['product_name'];

                        $product_img = $rows['product_image'];

                 ?>
                    <div style="border: 2px solid green; height: 350px; "  class="col-lg-4">
                            <form method="get" >

                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product_name ; ?>" name="product_name">    
                            <strong style="font-size: 24px; color: brown"><?php echo $product_name ; ?></strong>
                            <img class="thumbnail" style="border: 1px solid gray" src="images/<?php echo $product_img; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" alt="54">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Qty</label>
                            <select onchange="change_country()" name="quant" id="quant" style="width: 100px;" class="form-control">
                                <option selected="">Select</option>
                                <?php

                                    $sql = "select * from quantities where product_id = 1";
                                    $run_sql = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_sql))
                                    {
                                        $quantity_id = $row['quantity_id'];
                                        $product_id = $row['product_id'];
                                        $quantity = $row['quantity'];
                                        $quantity_price = $row['quantity_price'];
                                 ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $quantity;  ?>"><?php echo $quantity; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" name="id">
                        </div>
                        <div id='state' class="form-group">

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Add item" name="add_item">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </form>
              <?php      }?> 

</div></div></div></div></div>
```

/// Ajax Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_country()
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?country="+document.getElementById("quant").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;  
    }
</script>
```

Ajax.php code

```
<?php

        $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','orderdryfruits');

        if(!$db)
        {
            die("connection".mysqli_error($db));
        }       

        $country  = $_GET['country'];

    if($country != "")
{

        $res = mysqli_query($db,"select * from quantities where quantity = $country");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
?>
<label style="margin-right: 2px;">Price</label><input style="width: 100px; type="text" name="Price" value="<?php echo $row['quantity_price'] ?>"> 

<?php }?>
```

I will be very thankyou if you guyz highlight where  i am missing

Comment: First of all, you miss any securtiy in your code. http://bobby-tables.com better learn about SQL Injections and how to prevent them by using prepared statements. Right now your whole database could be deleted in a few seconds.

Comment: so, i need to do it, i have to submit it some where,

Comment: All I'm saying is that you should use prepared statements for your queris. Right now your queries aren't safe. Don't put any POST / GET parameter directly in your queries. Just visit the page I mentioned and look on how to use prepared statements. That won't solve your problem, but will first of all help you improve in security for your application, what in my opinion, is way more important.

Comment: Yes, thank you, btw did you understand my code?

Comment: Yes, I have. I simply refuse to give any advise on insecure code. Everyday I see people posting here with queries widly open to SQL inejctions. Change your query to a prepared statement, edit your post here, and I'm ready to help you to solve your problem. Before that, I won't help you.

Comment: Ok sir, i will learn it definatily